# Js How to draw line to edge of circle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having issues, drawing lines between two circles.

The main issue is that the lines are drawn to the square of the div, not the circle defined with border-radius.

In the code pen below you can see box E is square and the line goes all the way, however, with circle F it does not reach.

It seems if the div aligns with the x or y the gap is less than say directly in a corner.

https://codepen.io/crankd-media/pen/poebQGM

```
var c1 = new Connector(
  {
    ele1: start, 
    ele2: end, 
  }
);
```

The line is going to the square of the div, not the circle radius:
[image: Image explaining the line is going to the square of the div, not the circle radius]

The circle will also need to be transparent so can't go to the middle.

Comment: Hi, use `clip-path` to generate the shapes.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari I have tried that and still no luck, thank you for the idea, That's exactly what we are looking for. We need the browser to reads as circle.